# Update to Openrowset SQL SERVER 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-update, openrowset

I'm trying to do an UPDATE action to a remote table from a local query. Obviously i know it should be with an OPENROWSET but i don't know how to do it.

I know you can Insert to an OPENROWSET doing something like this:

```
 set @cadsql = convert(varchar(max),
  'insert into openrowset(''SQLOLEDB'','''+@cadcon+''','+@bd+'.ctoxtractor.lm_vehiculos) ' + char(13) + 
  '           (cuenta,corporativo,economico,ctatipotractor,sctatipotractor,ultcambio,ciausu,usuario,estatusoper) ' + char(13) + 
  'select 423,fv.vehic,fv.numeco,9802,0,getdate(),0,''ADMIN'',fv.estatusoper ' + char(13) + 
  'from ficvehic fv ' + char(13) + 
  'order by fv.vehic ')

 exec (@cadsql)
```

Or that i can do a select like this:

```
SET @cadsql = 'SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET(''sqloledb'',''driver=sql server;server='+@server+';database='+ @database +';uid='+@user+';pwd='+@password+''',' +
'''SELECT Column1, column2,...  
   FROM table'')'

INSERT INTO another_table
exec (@cadsql)
```

But i havn't come up with a solution for updating. Is that possible?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understand your intention correctly, this should get you going:

```
UPDATE target
SET
  target.column = query.value,
  ...
FROM OPENROWSET(
  'provider',
  'connection string',
  'SELECT columns FROM yourtable'
) AS target
INNER JOIN (
  your local query
) AS query
ON
  target.column = query.column
  AND ...
;
```

Basically, this is same as you would go about updating a local table from a query, just using OPENROWSET instead of a table name in the FROM clause and specifying its alias in the UPDATE clause.

Of course, it is also important that the remote query should be *updatable* (e.g. it should return results from a single table), same as with its being *insertable* when you are using OPENROWSET to insert.

Answer (score 2):

This is the syntax:

```
OPENROWSET 
( { 'provider_name' , { 'datasource' ; 'user_id' ; 'password' 
   | 'provider_string' } 
   , {   [ catalog. ] [ schema. ] object 
       | 'query' 
     } 
   | BULK 'data_file' , 
       { FORMATFILE = 'format_file_path' [ <bulk_options> ]
       | SINGLE_BLOB | SINGLE_CLOB | SINGLE_NCLOB }
} ) 

<bulk_options> ::=
   [ , CODEPAGE = { 'ACP' | 'OEM' | 'RAW' | 'code_page' } ] 
   [ , ERRORFILE = 'file_name' ]
   [ , FIRSTROW = first_row ] 
   [ , LASTROW = last_row ] 
   [ , MAXERRORS = maximum_errors ] 
   [ , ROWS_PER_BATCH = rows_per_batch ]
   [ , ORDER ( { column [ ASC | DESC ] } [ ,...n ] ) [ UNIQUE ]
```

And here you could get some more info

http://technet.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms190312.aspx

Comment: I think this is not helpful at all!

Answer (score 1):

A.F.A.I.K. The OPENROWSET function can also be referenced as the target table of an INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE statement, subject to the capabilities of the OLE DB provider. Although the query may return multiple result sets, OPENROWSET returns only the first one.

OPENROWSET can be used to access remote data from OLE DB data sources only if the DisallowAdhocAccess registry option is explicitly set to 0. When this option is not set, the default behavior does not allow ad hoc access.

OPENROWSET does not accept variables for its arguments.

**Syntax of OPENROWSET Function :**

```
OPENROWSET ( 'provider_name' 
    , { 'datasource' ; 'user_id' ; 'password'
        | 'provider_string' } 
    , { [ catalog. ] [ schema. ] object
        | 'query' }   )
```

provider_name is a character string that represents the friendly name of the OLE DB provider as specified in the registry. It has no default value.

datasource is a string constant that corresponds to a particular OLE DB data source.

userid is a string constant that is the username passed to the specified OLE DB provider.

password is a provider-specific connection string that is passed in as the DBPROP_INIT_PROVIDERSTRING property to initialize the OLE DB provider.

catalog is a name of the catalog or database in which the specified object resides.

schema is a name of the schema or object owner for the specified object.

object is a object name that uniquely identifies the object to manipulate.

query is a string constant sent to and executed by the provider.

Answer (score -1):

Updated..  Have a look here (final post one page)..  I don't know if this works or not, but seems plausible..

http://www.sql-server-performance.com/forum/threads/how-to-update-using-openrowset.10275/

I will see if I can get this working today while I am work..  I have a couple test dbs that I can play with..

```
update t set t.col_Name='1' FROM OPENROWSET('SQLOLEDB','ServerName';'UserName';'Pwd','select * from TableName') t
```

HTH,

Kent

Comment: Updated my answer..  HTH.  Kent

Comment: I have to ask..  Does not my updated answer address your problem?

Comment: Provided a real-world example of what I have used personally. Thanks Kent

Comment: What i need to do is to update to a REMOTE database. something like `update openrowset('SQLOLEDB', ...., table_to_update) SET remote_field1 = localquery_field1... `. of course that doesn't work, i'm just trying to tell you what i need

Comment: OK..  Getting closer..  I have updated my answer again..  Let me see if I can get it working.

Comment: That's not what i'm looking for. I need to update `TO` OPENROWSET. Update a remote table from a local query. Thanks for your enthusiasm!

Comment: OK..  I have to ask..  Why are you using OPENROWSET?  Why not use a SQL Job (formerly called a DTS Package)?  Thing that is helpful with a DTS, you can do what you want with linked servers, CSV, Excel, etc.

Comment: The reason is because here they have a lot of programs "interacting" each other. The query is running from one of the programs databases and also use a `SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET`. It's a mess!!! Thanks :(